# Easiest way to install replacement SSL certs in Amazon ubuntu hosting

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've got a site that I'm doing a mobile app for that needs a new SSL cert installed.  The new SSL certs have been purchased from GoDaddy, but I'm unsure as to which type to download as or how/where to even upload them.

**Could someone give me a simple guide?**

The site is hosted on EC2 and I can successfully ssh in using CyberDuck so far.

I've downloaded the GoDaddy certificates for Apache, so I have two .crt files:

- 1e7e53489b5d43db.crt
- gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt

Help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` you should have the config file for the VirtualHost you are using. Such file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin youremail@example.com
        ServerName example.com

        SSLCertificateFile /path/to/certificatefile
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/cetificatekeyfile
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

As you see, those two options starting by `SSLCertificate..` should be pointing to your current certificate files. You have to store you new ones somewhere, update those paths and restart (or reload) apache.